# SQL Query to select post title & post ID from a particular category from wordpress table

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for SQL query to select post title & post ID from a particular category. I looked at wordpress table structure but it is really confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one I've used.  You probably need to change (or remove) the `post_type` condition.  `tt.taxonomy` would probably be "category" in your case (sorry, not near a database to confirm).

```
SELECT p.ID
     , p.post_title
  FROM wp_posts p
       JOIN wp_postmeta pm on pm.post_id = p.id
       LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id
       LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
       LEFT JOIN wp_terms t on tt.term_id = t.term_id
 WHERE p.post_status = 'publish'
   AND p.post_type = 'event'
   AND tt.taxonomy = 'event_type'
   AND t.slug = 'atelier'
```

If you're running it from within WordPress you should use the `$wpdb` table names / prefix as a best practice.  This one's for running standalone.